# Subir multiples archivos via ftp con c#

Tags: c#

Estoy creando una plicacion en `C#` con  `FileSystemWatcher`, Estoy intentado  subir multiples archivos al `servidor web` via `FTP`

La idea es la siguiente:

He creado una carpeta en `C://` donde los usuarios  `copiaran,moveran y renombraran` archivos. estos archivos tendre que ordenarlos  y renombrarlos, para posteriormente subirlos al servidor.

El codigo es el siguiente:

Esta funcion se encarga de subir los ficheros al servidor:

```
/*ftp data*/
   private String servidor = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servidorFTP"];
   private String usuario = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["usuarioFTP"];
   private String clave = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["claveFTP"];
   private String puerto = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["puertoFTP"];
  
  private void uploadFile(String fileName, String fileFullPath){
            //preparo la direccion donde se almacenara el archivo en el servidor
            string url = servidor + fileName;       
            var ftpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as FtpWebRequest;
            ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
           
           //me logeo en el servidor
            ftpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, clave);
            byte[] fileData = GetFileData(@fileFullPath);
            using (var requestStream = ftpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            }
            var response = ftpWebRequest.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
  }
  
  private byte[] GetFileData(String filename){
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename))
      {
          return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());
      }
  }
```

Este codigo va bien si se trata de un solo fichero, pero cuando intento subir varios a la vez el codigo no funcciona correctamente.

Tambien si ejecuto la funcion para mover el documento al nuevo directorio. Este crashea ya que el mover archivo localmente se ejecuta mas rapido que el subir

codigo para mover:

```
 private void moverArchivo(String archivo){
    System.IO.File.Move(carpetaWatch + "\\" + archivo, carpetaWatch + "\\" + anoActual + "\\" + archivo);
 }
```

Comment: No entiendo el problema.. si funciona para uno, para que lo haga para muchos sera lo mismo pero de a uno por vez...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileSystemWatcher solo te sirve con entornos locales, no remotos. Cuando trabajas con FTP. Desde el lado del servidor nunca sabes cuándo el archivo dejo de manipularse, únicamente que hubo una afectación en el directorio, que puede ser que el archivo fue creado y está empezando a ser transferido; no vas a recibir una notificación del systemwatcher cuando el archivo dejo de ser modificado.

En una empresa que trabaje tenían trabajo con FTPs. Para indicar que el archivo se ha terminado de subir, agregaban un archivo "semáforo", que es un archivo vacío con el mismo nombre, y un sufijo s. Ejemplo: "archivo.zip" y "archivo_s". Esto permitía a una aplicación de consola mover nada más aquellos archivos que explícitamente habían sido marcados como transferidos exitosamente.

Una conexión FTP puede fallar, nunca vas a saber si el archivo está completo. FTP es un protocolo propenso a muchos fallos externos. Puedes generar una estrategia de lectura, si un archivo tiene un número N de minutos de producido y no contiene un archivo semáforo. Seguro, fallo algo en la transferencia. Si el archivo contiene su semáforo, la transferencia fue exitosa, y finalmente, si el archivo fue creado, no ha pasado el tiempo límite, y no tiene semáforo, entonces, el archivo está siendo trabajado.